# Efficiency of power function in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am writing a code where the main time bottleneck is the utilisation of power function (apparently w_pow.c from glibc). I am calling it to compute power 2 mainly.

```
b=a**2
```

Would it be faster to write :

```
a*a
```

instead of a**2? Or would it be better to have another library?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely common for compilers of many compiler languages, including Fortran, to transform one to the other, depending on which one is faster.

Computing `a^2` as a multiplication `a*a` is faster on normal CPUs, but the compiler will do that for you when you write `a**2`. The is no need to worry about these details.

You can try it at https://godbolt.org/z/5Ebde4 Conveniently, the default example for Fortran at godbolt.org is a square function, so you can very easily compare the assembly for `x**2` and `x*x` and enable optimizations (say `-O3`).

Comment: It's probably faster to do a few of these at a time rather than one by one. One could test a few  approaches.